# javascript function internal scope property

Tags: javascript

What is the Difference in internal scope property assigned on function declaration and on entering the function execution context?

**Definition:**
`[[Scope]] property is already written and stored in function object. [[Scope]] in contrast with Scope (Scope chain) is the property of a function instead of a context.`

Link:(http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/chapter-4-scope-chain/#function-creation)

What i mean is :as soon as function gets declared will it be assigned scope property or during execution time will scope property gets assigned.

Comment: Link to source where you got this information from may be useful...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov i provided the link ,the definition is under the topic "function creation"

Answer (score 0):

This is the closure concept.  It is worded differently here than normal.  Basically there are two things going on -- first you have the closure, that is the variables that are declared locally to the context of the function definition are made available to the function.  This is the "scope chain" he refers to.  In addition, locally defined variables (var statements within the function) don't exist until the function starts at "execution context".  (Typically these are stored on the stack or a heap).

Comment: this means internal scope property is assigned to function at declaration also at execution right?

Comment: @Maizere - that question does not make sense to me.  What do you mean by assigned, what do you mean by declaration, what do you mean by execution?

Comment: is the [[scope]] prop assigned at function declaration or after execution?:?

Comment: It is created on entering the context and updated on execution as your link states.

Comment: Important point -- this article is discussing his implementation -- it does not mean this is the best or only way to implement JavaScript.  In fact, I believe most JavaScript is implemented differently.